# c++ memory leak using threads

Tags: multithreading, c++11, memory-leaks, new-operator, delete-operator

I have a memory leak with this piece of code and I don't understand why.

Each thread calls the function exec. The function exec simply creates a std::vector and than delete it. This vector has length equal to the number of threads and it is created, and deleted, only once.

You can suppose that this code is thread-safe in the sense that the vector is deleted only after the creation.

```
class Foo{
  public:
  Foo(const std::size_t& numThreads):size_(numThreads){}
  inline void alloc(){std::call_once(bufferflag_,&Foo::alloc_,this);}
  inline void free(){std::call_once(bufferflag_,&Foo::free_,this);}

  private:
  const std::size_t size_;
  std::vector<double>* bufferptr_;
  std::once_flag bufferflag_;

  inline void alloc_(){bufferptr_ = new std::vector<double>(size_);}
  inline void free_(){delete [] bufferptr_;}
};

void exec(Foo& comm){
  comm.alloc();
  // sync the threads here with some barrier
  comm.free();
}

void main(){
  Foo comm(10);
  std::vector<std::thread> t(10);
  for(std::size_t tid=0;tid!=10;++tid) t[tid]=std::thread(exec,std::ref(comm));
  for(std::size_t tid=0;tid!=10;++tid) t[tid].join();
}
```

HEAP SUMMARY:

in use at exit: 104 bytes in 2 blocks

total heap usage: 23 allocs, 21 frees, 3,704 bytes allocated

104 (24 direct, 80 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 2 of 2

LEAK SUMMARY:

definitely lost: 24 bytes in 1 blocks

indirectly lost: 80 bytes in 1 blocks

possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks

still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks

suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks

**UPDATE**

If instead of using call_once I just call the new and delete from the same thread, there are no memory leaks.

Comment: Maybe you need to call bufferptr.clear() before deleting the pointer in exec function? 80B is sizeof(double) * 10

Comment: If I call bufferptr_->clear() before the delete the heap and leak summary is exactly the same.

Comment: How are you ensuring that `alloc` is called *before* `free`?

Comment: This program is one giant race condition.

Comment: Between the call of the alloc and of the free I use a barrier to synchronize the threads. I haven't posted the full code because it becomes to long and less readable. You can add a lengthy computation in order to be sure that the two function are called in the rigth order or implement a barrier to sync the threads.

Comment: Why are you even using dynamic allocation instead of simply [allocating and sizing the vector at Foo construction in the main thread](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b9a974ed7fc980a1)?

Comment: If you really want to offload the allocation and initialization of the vector from the main thread, [you may as well do everything in an asynchronous task](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/520bfd6d4a2ec933).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this modified code:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(const std::size_t& numThreads) :size_(numThreads) {}
    inline void alloc()
    {
        printf("alloc\n");
        std::call_once(alloc_flag, &Foo::alloc_, this);
    }
    inline void foo_free()
    {
        printf("free\n");
        std::call_once(free_flag, &Foo::free_, this); // Changed from bufferflag
    }
private:
    const std::size_t size_;
    std::vector<double>* bufferptr_;
    std::once_flag alloc_flag;
    std::once_flag free_flag;

    inline void alloc_()
    { 
        printf("once_alloc_!\n");
        bufferptr_ = new std::vector<double>(size_);
    }
    inline void free_()
    { 
        printf("once_free_!\n");
        bufferptr_->clear();
        delete bufferptr_; // Not delete[] bufferptr_
        bufferptr_ = NULL;
    }
};

void exec(Foo& comm){
    comm.alloc();
    // Barrier
    comm.foo_free();
}
```

If you **use 2 different once_flag for alloc and free**, you run also the free_() method. The fact that you are using only one flag generates a memory leak because the flag is *consumed* by the first alloc.

To check memory leaks I use `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();` and I get some extra leaks even if I comment out the thread create/join routines but I think this std::vector thrash. Hope this helps!